# Asp net core MVC Authorization with Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, asp.net-core-mvc, roles, active-directory-group, asp.net-authorization

In an Asp net core MVC application, I use Active Directory for automatic login like this :

```
this.user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(this.context, Environment.UserName);
```

and I get groups of the user with this :

```
public List<String> GetUserGroups()
{
   List<String> groups = new List<String>();
   foreach(GroupPrincipal gr in user.GetGroups())
   {
      groups.Add(gr.Name);
   }
   return groups;
}
```

And I would like to implement Autorisation with this groups, something like that :

```
[Authorize(Roles ="Admin")]
public IActionResult OnlyAdmin(){}
```

with something that link AD groups with authorization Roles or directly check authorization with AD groups if possible but I don't know how to do something like that.

*note : I haven't any login/logout pages, it's only automatic.*

**EDIT**

Don't know exactly why or how but it finaly work whithout any code and only with the user login in the PC not the user specified in `this.user` but it's fine like that.

But now I get a 404 error when I'm trying to access a denied page, why it's not a 401 or 403 error ? How can I redirect a denied access to a custom error page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the group in the ClaimsPrincipal class, i.e.

```
var claims = new List<Claim>();
claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username));
foreach (string userGroup in authResponse)
{
    claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, userGroup, ClaimValueTypes.String,"system","system"));
}

var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "authenticationScheme"));
```

Now use authorize attribute, either on controller or action as :

```
[Authorize(Roles = "guest,home")]
```

Comment: Thanks, it's work pretty well. but when I try to access a page without the access right needed, I get an error, any idea to how redirect this error to a proper "you don't have access to this" page ?

Comment: If you don't need any access right, just mark the controller/Action as Anonymous.

Answer (score 0):

You can write an ErrorHandlingMiddleware as follows. You will need to register it in the startup file

```
app.UseMiddleware(typeof(ErrorHandlingMiddleware));
```

following is an example for the same.
    public class ErrorHandlingMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

```
    public ErrorHandlingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILogger<ErrorHandlingMiddleware> createLogger)
    {
        this._next = next;
        this._logger = createLogger;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        var statusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;

        try
        {
            await _next.Invoke(context);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this._logger.LogError(ex, ex.Message);
            switch (context.Response.StatusCode)
            {
                case (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound:
                    statusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
                    break;
                case (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden:
                    statusCode = HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
                    break;
                case (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest:
                    statusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
                    break;
                default:
                    statusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                    break;
            }

            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)statusCode;
        }

        if (!context.Response.HasStarted)
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";

            var response = new { code = statusCode };

            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response);

            await context.Response.WriteAsync(json);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: After trying it, I finaly just use this code
 `app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Home/Error", "?statusCode={0}");`
With a simple exception handling in my controller : 
`public IActionResult Error(int? statusCode = null)
        {
            if (statusCode.HasValue)
            {
                if (statusCode == 404 || statusCode == 500)
                {
                    var viewName = statusCode.ToString();
                    return View(viewName);
                }
            }
            return View( }`
Bu I get a 404 error instead of a 403 or 401 error any idea ?

Comment: The last I remember that this was a known issue in .net core of not able to handle the 401 with UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute(). The suggestion was to use custom middleware.